# Kotlin - specify type explicitly in IntelliJ after extracting a variable shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

When coding in Java (and Kotlin!) in Intellij, I usually extract variables/fields from the expression that they are being assigned. In other words, if I want to write the following code in Kotlin:

> val name = getMyString()

Then I would write `getMyString`, highlight it and extract the variable using a keyboard shortcut. Nice and simple.

But let's say I want the value type to be shown explicitly, meaning:

> val name: String = getMyString()

If I use variable extraction, IntelliJ will offer me a checkbox, which I have to use my mouse to click, that will show the type. Another annoying option would be to set the variable name, then use Alt + Enter show the type explicitly.

Unlike previous questions (or JetBrains documentation), I do **not** want to have the type displayed by default. I just want to know if there is a keyboard shortcut to check the aforementioned checkbox, without disrupting the flow of writing the code.

Comment: when I use extract variable (Ctrl+Alt+V), I can use (Alt+T) toggle "Specify [t]ype explicitly" in the popup

Comment: @zapl this should really be an answer. But I'm curious: how did you discover Alt-T? On my OS at least (macOS), nothing indicates that this allows checking that checkbox. For the record, Alt-V checks the "Declare with var" checkbox (found out by guessing).

Comment: @JBNizet t and v are underlined on Windows.

Comment: @zapl Nice. Please turn this to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: SpecifyType popup]

After using the extract variable shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>
+<kbd>V</kbd> for Windows), you can use

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to toggle `Specify type explicitly`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to toggle `Declare with var`